# Spring - validation of Integer attribute

Tags: spring, validation, integer, notnull

I have entity:

```
public class User{
   @NotNull
   private Integer age;
}
```

In Restcontroller:

```
@RestController
public UserController {
 ..... 
}
```

I have BindingResult, but field age Spring doesn't validate. Can you tell me why?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Please post your controller method..

Comment: @RequestMapping("/users")
 public void addUser(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult result) {
        if(result.hasErrors()){  some action    }
    }

Answer (score 10):

If your posting something like JSON data representing the `User` class you can use the annotation `@Valid` in conjunction with @RequestBody to trigger validation of annotations such as the `@NotNull` you have on your `age` property. Then with `BindingResult` you can check if the entity/data has errors and handle accordingly.

```
@RestController
public UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<?> create(@Valid @RequestBody User user, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            // handle errors
        }
        else {
            // entity/date is valid
        }
    }
}
```

I'd make sure your `User` class also has the `@Entity` annotation as well.

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @NotNull
    @Min(18)
    private Integer age;

    public Integer getAge() { return age; }

    public setAge(Integer age) { this.age = age; }
}
```

You may want to set properties to output/log SQL so that you can see that the proper restraints are being added to the User table.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I do it, like you, but @NotNull on Integer attribute age not validation, but every for example String attribute works fine.

Comment: Try adding the validation annotation `@Min(1)` or `@Range(min=1, max=10000)` to the `Integer` age property and see if it successfully validates.

Comment: Yes, Thanks, I try it. But It is strange. On this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/ use @NotNull annotation on Integer attribute

Comment: Great to hear! I think @RestController needs the `@Min` or `@Range` because your data is coming in via JSON as a `String` for the `age` property. Try getting the JSON to send as a number instead if you can and `@NotNull` might be all you need. In the example the form the age field has a bean-backed property so it must be converting to a number on submit. The @Min or @Range implicitly converts to a number type when doing the check. Adding a `@Range` to something like age would make sense though as you wouldn't want user to enter age 999. Please mark answer that help you solve the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If needed you can specifiy default messages

@NotNull("message": "age: positive number value is required")

@Min(value=18, message="age: positive number, min 18 is required")

and please use dto's